# WP8 emulator 720 works with Hyper-V but not VS2013

Tags: windows-phone-8

The other types of emulator works fine only 720p emulator freezes my machine.
Also the 720p emulator works fine from Hyper-V but not from VS2013.
I'm using Windows 8.1 and VS2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, Locate :
C:\Users#Local User#\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\11.0
and delete 11.0 folder ,run VS2013 and try agin. Worked for me.

Comment: If you solved the problem, you should mark the answer as solution.